# RxJS Sequential Request and return Observable<> first response

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm not familiar with RxJS but I need to work on it for a project.

In my code, I have one function to create an owner that returns an Observable and I want to call the API to create a new Owner and another to associate the Car sequentially.

```
this.myRequestPost('myUrl', value).pipe(
 concatMap(my2ndRequest)
) as Observable<Owner>;
```

I just need to execute the second request but I don't want a different response. The problem is that result is incorrect and it's the only way I found to execute sequentially the request. I'm trying to find a way to execute the sequential requests by returning to the response of the first request.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you're trying to do. But I think you're looking for switchMap or CombineLatest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the result of the second request to the result of th first request:

```
this.myRequestPost('myUrl', value).pipe(
  concatMap(result1 => my2ndRequest.pipe(
    map(result2 => result1),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. It’s the solution